# Keep getting a Syntax error: unexpected 'INSERT' on a snowflake SQL query and I'm stumped?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sql-insert

Keep getting an error:

> Syntax error: unexpected 'INSERT'

in a Snowflake SQL query and I'm stumped. I am trying to create and insert data in a table. This query should correctly generate subclasses for each distinct class in `EV_RETAIL_TEST_DB.TEST_MODEL.DIM_ITEM_TEST` and insert them into the same table. The generated subclasses will have names like 'Subclass 1.1', 'Subclass 1.2', 'Subclass 1.3' for the first class, 'Subclass 2.1', 'Subclass 2.2', 'Subclass 2.3' for the second class, and so on.

```
WITH CLASSES AS 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT 'CLASS_NAME' AS CLASS_NAME
    FROM EV_RETAIL_TEST_DB.TEST_MODEL.DIM_ITEM_TEST
),
SUBCLASSES AS 
(
    SELECT 'C.CLASS_NAME' AS CLASS_NAME, 1 AS SUBCLASS_NUMBER, 'Subclass 1.1' as SUBCLASS_NAME
    FROM CLASSES C
    UNION ALL
    SELECT S.CLASS_NAME, S.SUBCLASS_NUMBER + 1, 'Subclass ' || S.CLASS_NUMBER || '.' || CAST(S.SUBCLASS_NUMBER + 1 AS VARCHAR) as SUBCLASS_NAME
    FROM 
        (SELECT 
             C.CLASS_NAME, 
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY C.CLASS_NAME ORDER BY C.CLASS_NAME) AS CLASS_NUMBER
         FROM 
             CLASSES C) CN
    INNER JOIN 
        SUBCLASSES S ON S.CLASS_NAME = CN.CLASS_NAME 
                     AND S.SUBCLASS_NUMBER = CN.CLASS_NUMBER - 1
    WHERE 
        s.subclass_number < 10
)
INSERT INTO EV_RETAIL_TEST_DB.TEST_MODEL.DIM_ITEM_TEST (CLASS_NAME, SUBCLASS_NUMBER, SUBCLASS_NAME)
    SELECT S.CLASS_NAME, S.SUBCLASS_NUMBER, S.SUBCLASS_NAME
    FROM SUBCLASSES S
    ORDER BY S.CLASS_NAME, S.SUBCLASS_NUMBER;
```

I have tried all of the following and nothing has worked so far:

The table `EV_RETAIL_TEST_DB.TEST_MODEL.DIM_ITEM_TEST` may not exist or may not have the necessary columns (`CLASS_NAME`, `SUBCLASS_NUMBER`, and `SUBCLASS_NAME`) for the `INSERT` statement.

The `DISTINCT` keyword in the `CLASSES` subquery may be unnecessary if `CLASS_NAME` is already unique in the table.

The `SUBCLASSES` subquery references `S.CLASS_NUMBER`, but the column is actually named `S.SUBCLASS_NUMBER`.

The string concatenation in the `UNION ALL` statement may not be supported by your database system. Try using a `CONCAT()` function instead.

The `INNER JOIN` clause in the `SUBCLASSES` subquery may be causing a circular reference or may not be necessary. Try removing it and see if the query runs successfully.

Comment: Snowflake does not support CTEs in `INSERT` statements, it's nothing more complicated than that. It only supports them for `SELECT`. Try creating a view with the same logic and using that as the source for your `INSERT`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Not entirely true.

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is move your INSERT to the top

```
INSERT INTO EV_RETAIL_TEST_DB.TEST_MODEL.DIM_ITEM_TEST (CLASS_NAME, SUBCLASS_NUMBER, SUBCLASS_NAME)
WITH CLASSES AS 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT 'CLASS_NAME' AS CLASS_NAME
    FROM EV_RETAIL_TEST_DB.TEST_MODEL.DIM_ITEM_TEST
),
SUBCLASSES AS 
(
    SELECT 'C.CLASS_NAME' AS CLASS_NAME, 1 AS SUBCLASS_NUMBER, 'Subclass 1.1' as SUBCLASS_NAME
    FROM CLASSES C
    UNION ALL
    SELECT S.CLASS_NAME, S.SUBCLASS_NUMBER + 1, 'Subclass ' || S.CLASS_NUMBER || '.' || CAST(S.SUBCLASS_NUMBER + 1 AS VARCHAR) as SUBCLASS_NAME
    FROM 
        (SELECT 
             C.CLASS_NAME, 
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY C.CLASS_NAME ORDER BY C.CLASS_NAME) AS CLASS_NUMBER
         FROM 
             CLASSES C) CN
    INNER JOIN 
        SUBCLASSES S ON S.CLASS_NAME = CN.CLASS_NAME 
                     AND S.SUBCLASS_NUMBER = CN.CLASS_NUMBER - 1
    WHERE 
        s.subclass_number < 10
)
SELECT S.CLASS_NAME, S.SUBCLASS_NUMBER, S.SUBCLASS_NAME
  FROM SUBCLASSES S
 ORDER BY S.CLASS_NAME, S.SUBCLASS_NUMBER;
```

Comment: I tried running it this way and it only updated 1 row

Comment: It depends on how your SQL returns data. Run your SELECT statement without the INSERT starting with WITH and verify the data set you'd like to insert in to your table.

Comment: ran the select statement and only came back with one set of update columns matching Subclass 1.1

Comment: Since I don't know your data set and don't have access to it, you will decide whether select statement's result is the desired output. Your question was about a syntax error with INSERT using CTE and I have corrected the syntax.